# personal cloud computing service

Tags: data-analysis, r, statistics, cloud, cloud-computing

I'm looking for a cloud computing service for my data analysis projects. I may be quite left alone in this, so I need it for myself alone.

I spent some time learning about most popular cloud computing providers, like AWS, MC Azure and also Rstudio cloud, which I like because I plan to use mostly, if not only, R and Rstudio.

However, Rstudio cloud doesn't seem very flexible, from August, it will offer only monthly subricption options, that don't come very cheap (full price is 99€).

What I would like, and still I haven't found, is a service that lets you work without hassles with a single thread, like Rstudio cloud free plan (it doesn't have to be free, but it must be cheap), and allows you to rent a powerful machine for limited time, when you need some brute computational force. This could take minutes or hours, and then you could switch back to the basic machine with the results when they are ready.

Am I dreaming? Does this exist anywhere? What's the available solution that is nearest to my needs?

Comment: How much space do you need?

Comment: i don't know right now, but i can pay for extra space, didn't think this can be a problem

Comment: If you can work with Python, Google Colab might be an option. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inN8seMm7UI Microsoft Azure Notebooks is similar. https://notebooks.azure.com/

Comment: that's nice, but it's just a jupyter notebook on the cloud, I can't see the pay-for-power option. the video that follows speaks about GPU backend, but that's not on the cloud.

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions as I've only dabbled in this. I was trying to share code with a client who couldn't or wouldn't install Python on their computer. I found Azure Notebooks nicer to use. I think there are paid options that might provide more computing horsepower. It also supports R.